# how to Change group subnav name on buddypres group single page

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

How to Change group subnav name on buddypres group single page.
I am working on a project in which using buddy-press i am going develop a job portal so in this case i have to change 'Home' subnav menu into 'Information'.
How i will able to change this and also delete some subnav menu.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'change_my_option_nav_name',9 );
function change_my_option_nav_name()
{
 global $bp;

 $bp->bp_options_nav[bp_get_current_group_slug()]['home']['name'] = 'Information';
}


 /* to remove unwanted menu */
 add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'remove_group_unwanted_subnav_tab',500 );
 function remove_group_unwanted_subnav_tab() {

  bp_core_remove_subnav_item( bp_get_current_group_slug(), 'admin' );
```

}

after all By doing above code i  finally get my result. Thanks